# Difference between Wordpress and Tumblr?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, tumblr

Newbee for Blogging Platform

I have an account with Wordpress and Tumblr ..!

In Wordpress, i can tag features which i believe more important for blogging sites.

In tumblr, all my blogs are located on same page .. i have to eventually scroll down .. and i dont see any tags ..!

If any expert can explain me about Difference or Merits of Wordpress or Tumblr .. i would be able to decide and go forward ..!

Thank you

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This question involves comparison of the **wordpress.com** and **tumblr.com** blogging services.

Answer (score 1):

The very first difference, is that tumblr is basicly an extended micro-blogging site, wordpress is a full featured blog and website.

For example, wordpress can be used as a portfolio page side-by-side with a blog and a news site and something else. Of course, you're  talking about wordpress.com, which has limitied capabilities compared to a standalon wordpress install.

Tumblr on the other side is an extended micro-blogging site, like Twitter, just you can add longer, lot longer postst, with pictures, videos, and so on.

For someone, who wants to create a blog (web-log, as web diary), both have the same possbilities, but if you want something, what can be extended, that's gonna be wordpress.

This is my opinion, of course.

Comment: I didn't know that Tumblr is an extended Microblogging. Thats really interesting. So in Tumblr, we can't have TAGS feature ??? Am i right ? Tumblr is just a plain blog site in which can add Video, Photo and "n" number of characters.

Comment: All the Tumblr-features (like asides, etc.) are also available with the latest wordpress version (3.1). So there's not really a difference. WP just does everything that tumblr does plus a lot more.

Comment: Kaiser, i am little confused on your comment " All the Tumblr-features (like asides, etc.) are also available with the latest wordpress version (3.1). " What are you trying to say exactly by that. Are you trying to say Wordpress has more features than Tumblr ..! Tumblr is just a basic blogging website ??

Comment: If Tumblr is a basic blogging website, Why it makes hot in the market ??

Comment: I think, in Wordpress we cannot follow other Users  .. , While in Tumblr i can follow other users  ..! Extended Microblogging or extended version of twitter ..!